# No entiendo por qué este bucle for se ejecuta cuando no debería en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Python y practicando haciendo una aventura de texto simple. Os pongo en situación:

He creado una clase para el objeto del jugador donde he puesto en un método todas las acciones que realizará según lo que el usuario escriba por pantalla. Estas acciones están en condicionales, y en una de ellas he determinado que diga lo que el jugador tiene en el inventario usando un bucle `for` que itere lo que hay en la lista que corresponde al inventario. Todas estas acciones las separo con `elif` poniendo como `else` que si no escribes ninguna de las acciones anteriores te diga que "*no entiende lo que dices*".

Pues bien, si escribo cualquier cosa que no corresponda con ninguna de las acciones se ejecuta el bucle `for` que itera el inventario, en lugar del `else` que dice que no entiende lo que dices. ¿Alguien sabe por qué ocurre esto? Os dejo el fragmento:

```
class player():
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
subir = False
bajar = False
inventary = []
coor = ""

def actions(self):
    self.coor = str(input("¿Hacia dónde quieres ir?: ").lower())
    if self.coor != "q":
        if self.coor == "n":
            self.y += 1

        elif self.coor == "s":
            self.y -=1

        elif self.coor == "e":
            self.x += 1

        elif self.coor == "o":
            self.x -= 1

        elif self.coor =="subir":
            if self.subir:
                self.z += 1
            else:
                print("No puedes subir")

        elif self.coor =="bajar":
            if self.bajar:
                self.z -= 1
            else:
                print("No puedes bajar")

        elif self.coor == "i" or "inventory":
            if len(self.inventary) == 0:
                print("No tienes nada en la mochila")
            else:
                print("Tienes:")
                for i in self.inventary:
                    print(i)
        else:
            print("¿Puedes repetir, por favor?")
            self.actions()
    else:
        global main
        main = False
        print("¡Nos vemos!")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

¿Por qué piensas que el `or` va a hacer las dos comprobaciones por ti?

```
elif self.coor == "i" or "inventory":
```

Si agrupamos con paréntesis tendremos la siguiente línea:

```
elif (self.coor == "i") or ("inventory"):
```

¿Qué resultado experarías tu si escribieses?:

```
if "inventory":
```

... pues eso. Esta condición será **siempre verdadera**, y eso explica por qué el programa ejecuta el código que no debe.

Tienes que hacer las dos comprobaciones explícitamente:

```
elif self.coor == "i" or self.coor == "inventory":
```

O bien puedes usar listas:

```
elif self.coor in ["i", "inventory"]:
```

Answer (score 2):

Porque en la línea donde testeas si ha solicitado el inventario has escrito:

```
elif self.coor == "i" or "inventory":
```

y esa línea es **siempre cierta** y por eso entra por ella en vez de por el `else`.

¿Por qué es siempre cierta? Porque el `or` no hace lo que pretendías, sino que mira si, o bien lo que está a su izquierda (`self.coor == "i"`) o bien lo que está a su derecha (`"inventory"`) es verdadero.

En tu caso, si pones cualquier cosa distinta de `"i"` lo que está a su izquierda será falso, pero eso no importa porque lo que está a su derecha es siempre verdadero, ya que se trata de la cadena `"inventory"` y para Python cualquier cadena no vacía equivale al booleano `True` cuando se usa en un contexto booleano (la cadena vacía sería `False`).

Lo que querías hacer era mirar si `self.coor` era igual a `"i"`, o si era igual a `"inventory"`, y eso tienes que describirlo explícitamente con dos comparaciones:

```
elif self.coor == "i" or self.coor == "inventory":
```