# While siempre hace break

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones, while, math

Para practicar con el While en Python hice un pequeno programa que calcula raizes cuadradas mientras que el cliente no le de "y" o "Y" a la pregunta de si quiere salir. Pero asi no le de "y" o "Y" hace break. Cual es el problema?
Gracias.

```
import math

def raiz():
    numero = float(input("La raiz de: "))
    a = print("Raiz: ", math.sqrt(numero))
    b = input("Parar?")

parar = input("Parar?")

while parar != "y" or "Y":
    raiz()
    if parar == "y" or "Y":
        break
```

Comment: Esta pregunta es básicamente igual a esta otra https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/311599/7123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juan Felipe:

En este caso, tendrías que además comprobar si hay alguna entrada de datos. Para que el cliente no haga intro sin insertar ninguna cadena y no haga un break.

Podrías cambiar la condición del while:

```
while parar not in ("y", "Y") or not parar:
    raiz()
```

En este caso comprueba si lo que se introduce a través del input no es una entrada vacía (not parar) además de comprobar si la entrada no es ni el string "y" ni "Y".

Podría refactorizarse el código mucho más (comprobar que la entrada de datos no es un string, por ejemplo), pero para lo que necesitas entiendo que es suficiente.

Edito todo el código con lo que podrías hacer que funcione correctamente:

```
import math

def raiz():
    numero = float(input("La raiz de: "))
    print("Raiz: ", math.sqrt(numero))

parar = input("Parar?")

while parar not in ("y", "Y") or not parar:
    raiz()
    parar = input("Parar?")
```

Comment: Esto sucede porque en el bucle estás comprobando "parar", en cambio una vez que llama a raiz(), el input lo asignas a la variable "b" y esta variable es válida solamente dentro del método, por lo que el while no la tiene en cuenta y "parar" sigue valiendo lo mismo que insertaste la primera vez. Podría refactorizarse mucho más pero entiendo que para lo que necesitas estás bien. Otra cosa, estás asignando a una variable (a) un print. Esto no es válido ya que lo que harías es asignar algo vacío y la variable sería None.

Answer (score 1):

Espero poderte ayudar:

```
import math

def raiz():
    numero = float(input("La raiz de: "))
    a = print("Raiz: ", math.sqrt(numero))

parar = input("Parar?")
while parar.upper() != 'Y':
    raiz()
    parar = input("Parar?")
```

Comment: Si agregas una explicación a tu código seguro que le ayudas más amigo

Comment: Se considera de baja calidad responder solo con codigo, porfavor leer. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

te recomendaria hacer un while en el que siempre tire el input hasta que pongas un numero que nadie pondria ej: -999 ya que sino tendrias que poner mas inputs al no poder poner lo que ingresa el usuario como un int o un float

quedaria asi

```
import math

teclado=float(input("Ingrese el numero a hacer la raiz o -999 para finalizar"))
while teclado != -999:
    print(math.sqrt(teclado))
    teclado=float(input("Ingrese el numero a hacer la raiz o -999 para finalizar"))
```